# Creating a table in Oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, table

I am trying to create a table inside a procedure but getting some issues related to quote identifier or may be something else.

```
BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'Create newTable as select * from oldTable';
END;
```

This's working fine however I need to create my table as

```
BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'Create newTable as select * from oldTable where col1='XXX' and col2='Y'';
END;
```

above statement is throwing errors.

I tried to change like this but this is also not working.

```
BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'Create newTable as select * from oldTable where col1="XXX" and col2="Y"';
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
begin
  execute immediate 'create table t1 as select * from dba_users where username  =''BP''';
end;
/

SQL> select username from t1;

USERNAME
----------
BP
```

Double quotes (`"`) have a different meaning than having mutliple single quotes after each other (`''`). Use this:

```
BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'Create newTable as select * from oldTable where col1=''XXX'' and col2=''Y''';
END;
```

Comment: how to execute multiple create statements in procedure.. for example if I have to execute similar types of statement s as shown above

Comment: @vikrantrana Specify multiple `execute immediate` statements.